# Why does this Implementation of Memoized Fibonacci not work?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, fibonacci

```
class Fib {
  public Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

  Fib() {
    memo.put(0, 1);
    memo.put(1, 1);
  }

  public Integer fibonacciMemoized(Integer n) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
      return memo.get(n);
    } else {
      int fibo = fibonacciMemoized(n-1) + fibonacciMemoized(n-2);
      return memo.put(n, fibo);
    }
  }
}
```

This code gives a `NullPointerException`. However, if I break up the last return statement to:

```
 memo.put(n, fibo);
 return fibo;
```

then it works. How come? Doesn't `put()` return the value that's put into the map?

Comment: No it does not return that value that has been put:, it returns "the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key." see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-

Comment: put will return previous value and not the new value.

Comment: If you use Java 8, you can use `Map`'s `.computeIfAbsent()`

Comment: Not related to your question, but a map with all integers from the range `[0, n)` as keys is better known as an array/list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it does not**. You can read in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)), there it clearly states that `put` returns the **previous** value associated with key, or `null` if there was no mapping for key.

> `V put(K key, V value)`
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)
>
> **Parameters:**
>   key - key with which the specified value is to be associated
>   value - value to be associated with the specified key
>
> **Returns:**
>   the **previous** value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

So, for your code the following must be used:

```
memo.put(n, fibo); // will NOT return the value
return fibo;       // and here it is returned
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Map.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) returns **the previous value for the given key**, not the value you're now assigning to it. In your case, you call `put` when you first encounter each key, so it will return `null`.